# Flutter GetX state management does not work

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

The problem I am facing is the ui text doesn't get updated. The data I want, in this case placeName, printed successfully on DEBUG Console, but it doesn't change Text widget UI. I thought in simple statement management in Getx, it would update the variable using update() in a method. I faced similar situation and I couldn't figure that out before, so I had to use statefuleWidget to solve it. But, this time I would like to continue this with Getx.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2qd4.gif)

Could anybody please help me?

2021-11-10
I updated my code, but it still doesn't work

2021-11-18
I figured it out changing return type of function(searchCoordinateAddress) and assign it to the variable(pickUpLocation) that I wanted to update.

```
// home_controller.dart
class HomeController extends GetxController {
  ...
  Rx<Address> pickUpLocation = Address().obs;
  RxBool isLoading = false.obs;
  ...


void locatePosition() async {
  ...
  ...

//  String? address = await UberRepository.to.searchCoordinateAddress(position); // previous

// current
 Address? address = await UberRepository.to.searchCoordinateAddress(position);
 pickUpLocation(address);
 isLoading(true);
}


// previous
/*
void updatePickUpLocationAddress(Address pickUpAddress) {
print("pickUpAddress.placeName: ${pickUpAddress.placeName}");
pickUpLocation(pickUpAddress);
print("pickUpLocation.value.placeName: ${pickUpLocation.value.placeName}");
  }
}
*/
```

```
// uber_repository.dart
class UberRepository extends GetConnect {
  static UberRepository get to => Get.find();

  @override
  void onInit() {
    httpClient.baseUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/';
    super.onInit();
  }

  // Future<String?> // previous
  // current
  Future<Address?> searchCoordinateAddress(Position position) async {
    String placeAddress = "";

    String url =
        'maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${position.latitude},${position.longitude}&key=$mapKey';

    final response = await get(url);

    if (response.status.hasError) {
      Future.error(response.statusText!);
    } else {
      placeAddress = response.body["results"][0]["formatted_address"];

      Address userPickUpAddress = Address();
      userPickUpAddress.latitude = position.latitude;
      userPickUpAddress.longitude = position.longitude;
      userPickUpAddress.placeName = placeAddress;


      return userPickUpAddress; // current

      // HomeController().updatePickUpLocationAddress(userPickUpAddress); // previous


    }
    // return placeAddress; // previous
  }
}
```

```
// home.dart
class Home extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const Home({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
...
 body:  Stack(
          children: [
            GoogleMap(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: controller.bottomPaddingOfMap.value,
              ),
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
              initialCameraPosition: controller.kGooglePlex,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
              zoomControlsEnabled: true,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController googleMapController) {
                controller.controllerGoogleMap.complete(googleMapController);
                controller.newGoogleMapController = googleMapController;
                // when map created and map is set correctly, call current location
                controller.setBottomPaddingOfMap();
                controller.locatePosition(); 
              },
            ),
...
...
Expanded(
    child: Obx(() => 
                  Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                 children: [
                    // TODO: UI update...
                    !controller.isLoading.value
                          ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                          : Text(
                             controller.pickUpLocation.value != null
                          ? controller.pickUpLocation.value.placeName!
                               : "Add Home",
                               maxLines: 2,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            softWrap: false,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 4.0),
                              Text(
                                "Your living home address",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                  fontSize: 12.0,
                   ),
                   ),
                  ],
            ),
           ),
     ),
...
```

```
// address.dart
class Address {
  String? placeFormattedAddress;
  String? placeName;
  String? placeId;
  double? latitude;
  double? longitude;

  Address({
    this.placeFormattedAddress,
    this.placeName,
    this.placeId,
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `Obx`. In your controller class do something like this

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {

     Address get pickupLocation => _pickupLocation.value;

  set pickupLocation(Address value) {
    _pickupLocation.value = value;
  }

  Rx<Address> pickUpLocation= Rx<Address>(Address());
  ...
  ...
  ...


  void updatePickUpLocationAddress(Address? pickUpAddress) {
    pickUpLocation = pickUpAddress;
    print("Here? ${pickUpLocation!.placeName!}"); // printed correctly as I intended
  }
}
```

Now in your UI class use Obx instead of GetBuilder Like this

```
// home.dart
class Home extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const Home({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
...
...
...
...
            Obx(() => controller.pickupLocation.placeName != null
                        ? Text(controller.pickupLocation.placeName)
                        : Text('Add home')),
...
```

Comment: I followed your code, and there were null check error, and I moved Obx(() => ) to parent Widget, and the error is gone, but the placeName data is '', empty string. I think it doesn't apply to the ui... What should I do?

Comment: I can print the data that I want on HomeController, but the ui side doesn't update and it shows ("") empty String. So, I guess that build Method of Home, return Widgets earlier than HomeController, therefore the data doesn't apply to the ui. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: Call the api method inside onInit(), and add a flag to track if the response you have gotten yet. When you are loading state you can show a progress dialog, when the pickupLocation is updated with api value, update the state.

Comment: I am still struggling with this matter... I added isLoading Rxbool variable on Controller, and I coded when it is true, show the placeName, also I checked printing pickUpLocation.value.placeName is updated earlier than isLoading becomes true. But, controller.pickUpLocation.value.placeName on UI side is null. What should I do? It is so frustrating

Comment: Does values in controller gets updated?

Comment: Yes, I can print and placeName got updated on DEBUG CONSOLE if it is what you ask me of
But, on UI it doesn't get updated. 

If I print (controller.pickUpLocation.value.placeName) below build method in UI file, it shows 'null' on DEBUG CONSOLE.

How can I notify placeName is changed to UI side? I tried update method and pickUpLocation.refresh();  in controller. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I figured it out changing return type of searchCoordinateAddress function from Future<String?> type to Future<Address?> in UberRepository and assign return value to address variable in locatePosition function in HomeController. After that, I updated pickUpLocation with address, then UI got updated successfully.

So,  updatePickUpLocationAddress function in HomeController is unnecessary now.

But, I still doubt that why previous way didn't update UI even it state was changed.
I continue the project for now without it, but I hope to find the way in the future.

Thank you, Inan Mahmud!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to call `pickUpLocation.refresh()` in your widget. Here is the relevant part from an example from getx dev page https://pub.dev/packages/get:

```
// `Rx` don't have any clue when you change something inside user.
// So, for custom classes, we need to manually "notify" the change.
user.refresh();
```

Comment: I added pickUpLocation.refresh() in updatePickUpLocationAddress function, it doesn't work, and I used update method, like below,
```    
pickUpLocation.update((value) {
      value!.placeName = pickUpAddress.placeName;
    });
```
ui still doesn't update...

I only can see the placeName is printed correctly... but not on UI side.